# Retrieve Object ID after save asp.net mvc LinqToSQL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I want to retrieve the ID of the object I have just saved so I can display it to the user for future reference. Without generating the ID myself what is the best way to do this because the database auto generates the ID.

I have the following method in my repository to save to the database and I want to retrieve the ID of the saved advert immediately after:

```
    public void SaveNewSomeObject(SomeObject someObject)
    {
        db.SomeObjects.InsertOnSubmit(someObject);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this retrieving the ID of the object that was inserted right after the submit changes

```
   db.SomeObjects.InsertOnSubmit(someObject); 
   db.SubmitChanges()
   MessageBox.Show(someObject.SomeID)
```

or another choice could be

```
var lastid = db.SomeObjects.OrderByDescending(x => x.SomeID).FirstOrDefault();
int id=lastid.SomeID;
```

Comment: How would this handle two people submitting records at the exact same time... I mean it generally shouldn't be an issue, but isn't this introducing an opportunity for error? and a potential hidden bug for down the line that would only occasionally show?